# Baking sheet in air fryer, and alternatives

Tags: baking, air-frying

I want to bake cookies in the air fryer but unfortunately I have no baking sheet. I am thinking maybe to use parchment paper or aluminium foil above the air fryer base. However, it seems a lot of experiences that people have with aluminium foil in air fryer seems negative.

But I really do wonder, do I actually even need a baking sheet for air fryer? If yes, what would be some alternatives?

The air fryer I am using: Ninja Air Fryer Max XL 1750W 5.2L

Comment: What type of airfryer do you have? A basket type? Paddle type? Or an oven type?

Comment: What type of air fryer to you have?  There are ones that are shaped like a toaster oven, some of which can just be used as a convection oven and would likely have no problems with this… the ones where the fans are above a cooking basket are going to be more problematic.  (And don’t use aluminum flashing…. It has a protective coating on it)

Comment: Air fryers are convection ovens with extra steps, so you need to be careful using an actual sheet pan as that could block the air flow and prevent the air fryer from working properly. That said, they do make [circular silicone baking mats](https://www.amazon.com/Silicone-Reusable-Diameter-Perfect-Premium/dp/B07RF9271J/) that you could look into that could work as long as you get one that's small enough to leave an inch or so of a gap around the edges so the air can circulate.